# Expected token Semicolon got 'Identifier' Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);

Tags: error

```
function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) {             
    if (balanceOf[msg.sender] < _value) throw;                // Check if the sender has enough
    if (balanceOf[_to] + _value < balanceOf[_to]) throw;      // Check the overflows
    if (frozenaccount[msg.sender]) throw;                     // Check if frozen
    balanceOf[msg.sender] -= _value;                          // Subtract from the sender
    balanceOf[_to] += _value                                  // add the same to the recipient
    Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value); (right here error!)                        // notify anyone listening that this transfer took place
}
```

all code 
https://gist.github.com/Sexstasy/86e8b243422aef64c3182fbd0ef1671e

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a semicolon on the preceding line.

Answer (score 0):

Correct code :

```
 function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) { 
if (balanceOf[msg.sender] < _value) throw; // Check if the sender has enough 
if (balanceOf[_to] + _value < balanceOf[_to]) throw; // Check the overflows 
if (frozenaccount[msg.sender]) throw; // Check if frozen balanceOf[msg.sender] -= _value; // Subtract from the sender 
balanceOf[_to] += _value; // add the same to the recipient 
Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value); // notify anyone listening that this transfer took place 
}
```

You should use require or assert instead throw, and use the safemath library